# mysql delete join fails for no reason?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I am trying to do a join delete and it times out. Not sure if it is a cross join issue or a MySQL issue on my box. win 7 64, with MySQL 5.7.17 community.

had an issue with vipre av competing with trend wfb 9 last time this issue started and resolved itself (was testing AV products and I know you should not have 2 installed). I am planning on moving my small data mart to MySQL but can't figure out what is causing this issue and can't base everything on MySQL if I can't figure out what is going on.

So the SQL that keeps timing out is:

```
DELETE prod
FROM cmdata.vauto_feed_options as prod
INNER JOIN cmdata.vauto_feed_options_cache stage
using ( stock__ )
```

or

```
delete prod
FROM cmdata.vauto_feed_options as prod
INNER JOIN cmdata.vauto_feed_options_cache stage 
ON ( prod.stock__ = stage.stock__
AND prod.vin = stage.vin)
```

or many other combinations of that with no luck. 
the table does not have a natural primary key, and the only composite key would be all the fields. This is part of a data ELT and I just want to remove all traces of old data and load the new data for the records that arrived, while keeping old records that were not just sent as a text file (so no truncate table).

I have flipped innodb to myisam and back, deleted the table and recreated, excluded the path from av scans, disabled av, removed av (antivirus). I added va_option_id as an auto number pk just to have one.

new data comes in that has 50 to 100 records per vin and stock combo and the features text is different (floor mat, dvd player, etc). Actually normalized from a single field in a csv file to rows for my storage.

```
delete prod CREATE TABLE `vauto_feed_options` (
  `va_option_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Stock__` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `VIN` varchar(17) NOT NULL,
  `Features` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`va_option_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=297269 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

296303 records

```
CREATE TABLE `vauto_feed_options_cache` (
  `Stock__` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VIN` varchar(17) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Features` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

58151 records

just did a similar delete join on a much larger dataset with no issue but those other tables have a nice primary key consistency (1 to 1)

```
delete prod 
FROM tblname_cache 
INNER JOIN  tblname as prod 
ON (  prod.company_number = tblname_cache.company_number 
AND  prod.record_key = tblname_cache.record_key )
```

Comment: guessing it could be the new cross join that is implicit above with a vin and stock with unique feature text joining to another vin and stock combo with 50 to 100 other unique feature values.

     SET timestamp=1489169267;
    delete cmdata.vauto_feed_options 
    FROM cmdata.vauto_feed_options ,     cmdata.vauto_feed_options_cache
    where cmdata.vauto_feed_options.stock__ =    cmdata.vauto_feed_options_cache.stock__
AND cmdata.vauto_feed_options.vin = cmdata.vauto_f [truncated, 278 bytes total]

Comment: Start Time, User@Host, Query Time, Lock Time, Rows Sent, Rows Examined, Detail


2017-03-10T18:07:47, root[root] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]  Id:     4, 241.833845, 0.000000, 0, 302843058,

Comment: Also tried a delete from the main detail record that has 1 record per vin + stock combo and it also timed out.

    delete opt
    FROM cmdata.vauto_feed_options opt INNER join    vauto_feed_vehicles_cache veh
     on( opt.stock__ =  veh.stock__);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a index on the column __stock in both tables.

Comment: that worked. Delete takes 30 seconds but better than timing out with a fail. Didn't have this issue ins MS SQL.